# How can java.awt.Robot be made to respond to mouse drag events?

Tags: java, mouseevent, awtrobot

I'm writing a class that will allow users on other computers to control the contents of a JPanel, for use in a shared display system.  java.awt.Robot will allow me to perform mouse clicks and keyboard input, but it does not have a `mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt)` method. My client has `clientMouseReleased` (and `Pressed`) methods as part of a `MouseAdapter` listener that look like:

```
private void clientMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
{
    try
    {
        switch (evt.getButton())
        {
            case 1:
                remoteDesktop.mouseRelease(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                break;
            case 2:
                remoteDesktop.mouseRelease(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
                break;
            case 3:
                remoteDesktop.mouseRelease(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Where the `remoteDesktop` is a class containing a java.awt.Robot, and it executes a `Robot.mouseMove` and `Robot.mouseRelease` (or `Robot.mousePress`) in the method the client calls. I'd like to be able to write the `mouseDragged` in the same way, i.e., like this:

```
private void clientMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
{
    try
    {
        switch (evt.getButton())
        {
            case 1:
                remoteDesktop.mouseDragged(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                break;
            case 2:
                remoteDesktop.mouseDragged(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
                break;
            case 3:
                remoteDesktop.mouseDragged(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the high level idea is that you need to add mouse state to your program.

Your `remoteDesktop` will need to keep the state of the mouse.

```
private boolean mouseDown = false;
```

Then, on mouse press and release actions you need to set the flag appropriately.

Then, you need to add logic in the mouse move code.

```
if (mouseDown) 
    handelDrag();
else 
    handleMove();
```

That's the general idea of how I would go about it.